# Spark Graphx with Hbase table as Input

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have key/value stored in Hbase can i convert these key value pairs into graph using GRaphX like All keys,Column Qualifiers as -> Nodes  while all values-> as Attributes of edges connecting nodes ?

Any pointer will be of a great help

Answer (score 0):

consider using [apache phoenix](http://phoenix.apache.org/) instead of raw hbase api, it's a sql layer/JDBC driver for hbase, then you can use [JdbcRDD](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/JdbcRDD.scala) to import data to spark, and once it's loaded use Graphx or SchemaRDD

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the Hbase part of your question.

But the GraphX part of the answer to your question is:
Note that VertexId's need to be of type Long.
The Edge consist at least out of two Long values connecting the source and destination Vertexes.

Strings cannot be used as VertexId's. 
Usage of Strings as VertexIds is a feature request in the Apache Spark Developer Community: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3799